# How to use python to create every word list?

Tags: python

[image: wave + image file]

Here is wav and image file . and you can donwload it - https://www.dropbox.com/s/iuwt6boc2r2fotc/word_images_file.zip?dl=0

**1st step** create word list txt file for every word.

put image name to list , and the list name is every word.

**but I don't know how to write python code for create every word image list .**

example:

```
accordion-word.txt

  file 'accordion_1_musical_instruments.jpg'
  file 'accordion_2_musical_instruments.jpg'
  file 'accordion_3_musical_instruments.jpg'
  file 'accordion_musical_instruments.jpg'
```

**2nd step** create audio file list

**don't know how to use python write code to create list for every word audio.**

```
accordion-audio.txt

     file 'slience_2sec.mp3'
     file 'This_is_.mp3'
     file 'slience_2sec.mp3'
     file 'accordion.mp3'
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer os.listdir when I only need file names - Compared to full path that glob returns when absolute path is supplied to it.

I'm making a guess that images' name without numbers in it has same prefix with numbered ones. Regex went crazy without this premis.

---

Here's full code that does your stuff:

```
from os import listdir
import re

# Getting list of all image files in directory
location = 'X:test folder/'
image_list = [name for name in listdir(location) if name.endswith('.jpg')]


# Fetching all image keywords, separated by '_x'. ignoring file without it.
reg = re.compile(r'(^[^0-9]*(?=_[0-9]))')
keywords = [reg.match(name).group(0) for name in image_list if reg.match(name)]


# Create txt files per keywords
for keyword in keywords:
    filtered = [f"file '{name}'" for name in image_list if name.startswith(keyword)]

    with open(location + keyword + '-word.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write('\n'.join(filtered))


# Fetching .wav audio clips
audios = [f"file '{name}'" for name in listdir(location) if name.endswith('.wav')]

# Saving audio clips list
with open(location + 'audio.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write('\n'.join(audios))
```

Results: On My [server](https://nyarukoishi.mooo.com/results/).
You can make keyword section way simpler by using changing file names.

for example, air-conditioner_1 instead of air_conditioner_1. Then we know we need to separate at first underscore for all files to get keywords. Much simpler.

Comment: Thank you !  but  `PS C:\test\ttt> python .\get_list.py   File ".\get_list.py", line 16     filtered = [f"file {name}" for name in image_list if name.startswith(k)]                              ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Hold on, I may made mistake when copying.

Comment: I fixed. the cause is python version. I switch to python 3.8.3 . it works. before it's 3.7.

Comment: Glad to hear that! Didn't know that was new syntax added to 3.8.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I'm working on make audio list learn by your code.

Comment: I can make a audio list . but there's a issue. 

accordion-audio.txt

     1. file 'slience_2sec.mp3'
     2.file 'This_is_.mp3'
     3. file 'slience_2sec.mp3'
     4. file 'accordion.mp3'

The audio file order will not be changed. I don't know how to fix the order.

Comment: Do I ask the new question about make audio file ?

Comment: Okay. I'm writing on it. Thank you .

Comment: I post here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62368339/how-to-use-python-make-audio-list

Comment: Got it, might takes some time!

Answer (score 1):

You could use python built-in module glob.

For example to get a list of all mp3 file:

```
glob.glob('C:\Downloads\*.mp3')
```

Note that the path format in the example above is for window.